# Android Facebook LikeView onActivityResult not being called

Tags: android, facebook, webview, facebook-like

Currently, I am trying to use LikeView without having the native FB app installed. This results in using WebView.

When the native FB app is installed, it returns back to the host app by calling onActivityResult of the host activity. However, when the native FB app is not installed, it resorts to WebView but does not call onActivityResult after returning.

I want to handle when the user is returned to my activity after the Like button is clicked. Works in case of Native app but does not work with WebView